# Timer based status changes that are saved to database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP website using a MySQL database.

We have items that users create, that are on a timer, and once this timer has counted down, without user interaction (basically next time someone sees it) the status needs to have changed.

I'm not sure how to implement this in a way to be accurate to the minute.

So we have an object X, that expires at 10:15pm tommorrow, and the next person to see object X after that time has to see it as expired.

Is the correct way to do this to be the next time object X is loaded we check if it's expired, and if so, update the database?

What happens if 10 people load object X at the same time after it's expired, what's to prevent some sort of race condition from all 10 requests attempting to update the database?

Is there a cron job that runs every minute that I can some how make use of, or any type of timer in MySQL to kick off every minute checking for these and running a script?

I have several ideas on how it -could- be done, like those listed above, but I'm not sure what the most practical is, or what the standard way to do it is as I'm positive someone has solved this problem before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is the correct way to do this to be the next time object X is loaded we check if it's expired, and if so, update the database?

Why do you need to update the database? It seems like you might have some redundancy in your DB table - from what you've said, it sounds like you have (for instance) an `is_expired` column and then an `expires_at` column.

Why not just get rid of the `is_expired` column? It's cheap to compare 2 integers, so when you want to determine if something is expired, just fetch the `expires_at` column and compare with the current time. This avoids any race conditions with expiry, since nothing in the DB changes.

Comment: I have a status history table, and everytime the status changes it's recorded. For instance, we have a status that it goes into Voting and voting lasts 1 week. At the end of the week it goes into a Success or Failed.

Comment: Though seeing as this is the last status the object will get, it would make sense to "fake" the last status history based on if the current status is Failed or Passed due to expiration (it can expire before it ever goes into voting as well), will have to play around with that idea.

Comment: Marking as correct since it answers the question I asked. Realized though we do need to do some actions explicity on expire (send emails etc), so will probably use cron.

Comment: Note that you can combine `cron` with this - just have the cronjob check for anything with an expiry timestamp between the last time the job was run and the current timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with `cron` of course. Or with javascript native function `setInterval( "checkFunction()", 10000 );` to alter the db. Or you could use a date field in DB and check for expiration

Make a field date_to_expire as DATE , enter the expiration date and everytime you query for it check to see if the item is expired (this can go up to seconds)